# ArchUnit doesnt seem to cache analyzed classes

Tags: java, archunit

I wrote some ArchUnit-Tests using Jupiter. I found examples that indicated, you can write your ArchUnit tests using non static methods, like:

```
@Test
void enforceExceptionNames() {
    classes().that()
             .areAssignableTo(Exception.class)
             .and(modifier(PUBLIC))
             .and().areNotAnnotatedWith("some.qa.ExceptionNameFlaw")
             .should()
             .haveNameMatching(".*Exception").orShould()
             .haveNameMatching(".*Error")
             .check(modulClasses);
}
```

The advantage is, that you can do things that arent possible static - like extracting the packagename using reflection at runtime and other stuff.

But performance is poor. Like 1-10 seconds depending on size.

Eitherway ArchUnit states to have all Classes cached static.

Answer (score 4):

Your initial question didn't show how `modulClasses` is obtained. If you do

```java
class StandardCodeModuleTest {

    private final JavaClasses modulClasses = new ClassFileImporter().import...
```

then the (expensive) class file import will – usually (cf. [@TestInstance](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/TestInstance.html)) – be done for each test, without caching.

So yes, it totally makes sense to use [ArchUnit's support for JUnit](https://www.archunit.org/userguide/html/000_Index.html#_junit_support) with `@AnalyzeClasses`, as [you found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65951480/13134095). However, `@ArchTest` is not restricted to *static* fields or methods. You can also use non-static methods:

```java
@ArchTest
void enforceExceptionNames(JavaClasses modulClasses) {
    classes().that()
             .areAssignableTo(Exception.class)
             .and(modifier(PUBLIC))
             .and().areNotAnnotatedWith("some.qa.ExceptionNameFlaw")
             .should()
             .haveNameMatching(".*Exception").orShould()
             .haveNameMatching(".*Error")
             .check(modulClasses);
}
```

or non-static `ArchRule` definitions:

```java
@ArchTest
ArchRule enforceExceptionNames = classes()
             .that()
             .areAssignableTo(Exception.class)
             .and(modifier(PUBLIC))
             .and().areNotAnnotatedWith("some.qa.ExceptionNameFlaw")
             .should()
             .haveNameMatching(".*Exception").orShould()
             .haveNameMatching(".*Error");
```

Answer (score 3):

It semms caching ONLY occurs when using @AnalyzeClasses and @ArchTest annotated static fields or methods.

After transforming my tests to this pattern, performance skyrockets to 0.05 seconds!

```
@AnalyzeClasses(packages = "some.svc.gui.impl")
public class StandardCodeModuleTest extends StandardCodeTest {

    @ArchTest
    public static final ArchRule ENFORCE_EXCEPTION_NAMES = classes()
            .that()
            .areAssignableTo(Exception.class)
            .and(modifier(PUBLIC))
            .and().areNotAnnotatedWith("some.qa.ExceptionNameFlaw")
            .should()
            .haveNameMatching(".*Exception").orShould()
            .haveNameMatching(".*Error");
```